# nginxでサブドメイン名に指定したポート番号へフォワーディングしたい

Tags: nginx

nginx.confファイルの書き換えだけで実現できるものでしょうか？

[https://8001.example.com/へのリクエストをhttp://example.com:8001/へフォワーディングしたいです](https://8001.example.com/%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%92http://example.com:8001/%E3%81%B8%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99)。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

luaモジュールを使えば実現できそうです。

こちらにluaを使って proxy_pass の宛先を変数で指定するサンプルがあります。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/hiboma/20120205/1328448746

Hostを取得する方法もありますので、Hostのポート部分を取得し、上のサンプルのようにproxy_passの宛先を設定してあげればたぶんできるかと。
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/#ngx-req-get-headers